# Handshake frames manipulation

Tags: python, sockets, scapy, handshake, wpa

I intend to create a fake AP in order to send the frames received from the client to the real AP and,
of course, the frames received from the real AP to the client... all passing through the fake AP.

I will use hostapd to create the fake AP and scapy to sniff and manipulate the packets (changing only source and destination).

Basically, using python, this is what I'm going to do:

**Client->FakeAP->RealAP**
1) sniff the packet
2) change source and destination (src=FakeAP, dst=RealAP)
3) send the packet to the Real AP

**RealAP->FakeAP->Client**
1) sniff the packet
2) change source and destination (src=FakeAP, dst=Client)
3) send the packet to the Client

Here's the code:

```
from scapy.all import *

def manipulateAndSend(pkt):
    pkt[Ether].src= new_src_mac
    pkt[Ether].dst= new_dst_mac
    pkt[IP].src= new_src_ip
    pkt[IP].dst= new_dst_ip
    send(pkt)

sniff(iface="wlan0", prn=manipulateAndSend, filter="tcp", store=0)
```

My two questions are:

1) In hostapd I'm going to set a "whatever" WPA key, so how can I avoid to reject the authentication?

2) How can I edit the IP src and dst of the packet if the IP association starts after the authentication is complete?

Comment: Hey loop.  Could you use iptables to forward all the traffic from the fake AP to the Real AP and just use scapy to sniff it?  Is there a reason that you need to manipulate the packets with scapy?

Comment: Hey @Noob123, yes actually there is one simple and unavoidable reason, you have to change source and destination, otherwise you would forward the packet to yourself and in case you achieve to send the packet to real AP, the response from the real AP would be sent back to the client and not to you (fake AP).

Comment: Ok.  I see.  I was thinking of it this way.  I have a Raspberry Pi set up with hostapd as an AP.  I have a second wireless connection that connects the Pi to the real AP.  When someone logs on to the Pi AP, the traffic is sent through that AP to the "real" AP.  I could run scapy on the Pi and sniff the traffic.  Right now I use it as a TOR router.

Comment: Oh, you're suggesting basically an evil twin attack, an interface would work as fake AP and the other one would have internet access. Unfortunately, if you create the fake AP with the same protection of the real AP, you would need to know the wpa key and then set the hostapd.conf with that key.
Unfortunately I haven't found an option in hostapd that allows the connection even if the wpa key stored in hostapd.conf doesn't match the one sent by the client. The only solution would be to set the fake AP as OPEN, which is no solution at all, because fake AP and real AP should have same encryption.

Comment: I didn't mean to take this thread down a path you didn't intend.  Sorry about that.  But if you know the WPA key of the real AP, can't you use one wireless device to attach to it, with that WPA key and have the other wireless device broadcast your AP?  Then you can set the wpa_passphrase and ssid in hostapd to match the real AP so the client would assume it is the real AP.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that you would need to know the WPA key in order to do that.

Comment: Got it. Sorry, I thought you controlled the real AP as well.  Again, not on topic but what about ARP poisining the target client?  If my comments are way off from what you are trying to do, just tell my to stop posting.

Comment: Still the same problem, you would need access to the real AP in order to do an ARP poisoning.
No worries for the off topic.